# SharePoint Online Iterating through Document Libraries CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, client-object-model, list-item

I am trying to iterate though a document library and set each document/items within to inherit permissions (at the moment each doc/item is using uniquer permissions).

I am able to get the specific document library that I am interesting in, however I cannot at the moment iterate though each of the items/documents within it, but here is what I have so far:

```
Add-Type -Path "Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.dll"
Add-Type -Path "Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll"

$webUrl = "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite" 
$username = "####"
$password = "####"
$securePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$listname = "TestDoc";

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webUrl)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePass)


$web = $ctx.Web
$lists = $web.Lists
$ctx.Load($lists)
$ctx.Load($web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()


write-host `n "Web Url:" `n $web.Url

foreach ($list in $lists)
{

    if ($list.Title -eq "TestDoc")
    {
        #print list name if found
        write-host `n "Found the list:" `n $list.Title `n


            #attempting to iterate through items in the document library 
            foreach ($item2 in $list.Items)
            {
                #list the items/documents  in the document library
                write-host $item2.Title 
            }


    }
}
```

It is the `foreach` loop I am having trouble at the moment as I am not sure how to loop though each of the items/documents in the document library.

Any suggestions on the approach I should take would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should `load` the items before using it.

```
 $items = $list.Items
 $ctx.Load($items)
 $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 foreach ($item2 in $items)
 {
     #list the items/documents  in the document library
     write-host $item2.Title 
 }
```

For Inheriting Permission you can use [`ResetRoleInheritance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee535228(v=office.14).aspx)

```
$item2.ResetRoleInheritance()
```

Comment: It should be `ResetRoleInheritance` instead of `BreakInheritance`

Comment: not a problem, I updated your answer.

Comment: the script fails at "ctx.Load($item)" with error code:

Cannot find an overload for "Load" and the argument count: "1".
At C:\Users\setup\Desktop\Test-BreakInheritence-Script-SPOnline\Permissions-Inh
eritence.ps1:56 char:3
+         $ctx.Load($items)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Comment: Yep I have corrected the typo, however the it still errors on the line "$ctx.Load($items)":

Cannot find an overload for "Load" and the argument count: "1".
At C:\Users\setup\Desktop\Test-BreakInheritence-Script-SPOnline\Permissions-Inh
eritence.ps1:38 char:3
+         $ctx.Load($items)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Answer (score 1):

The error I was getting:

Cannot find an overload for "Load" and the argument count: "1". At C:\Users\setup\Desktop\Test-BreakInheritence-Script-SPOnline\Permissions-Inh eritence.ps1:38 char:3 + $ctx.Load($items) + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :

Was to do with the Load() method requiring additinal parameters passed into it. I think this is only required when dealing with lists/listItems. Did not spend too much time investigating the exact root cause, but I have reworked my solution and made it simpler:

```
Add-Type -Path "Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.dll"
Add-Type -Path "Libraries\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll"

$webUrl = "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite" 
$username = "####"
$password = "####"
$securePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$listname = "TestDoc"

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webUrl)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePass)


#get the List/DocLib and load it for use
$listUpdate = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listname)
$ctx.Load($listUpdate)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#CAML Query to get all items inclusing sub-folders
$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$spQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll' />";
$itemki = $listUpdate.GetItems($spQuery)
$ctx.Load($itemki)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#iterating through the items and reseting permission inheritence
for($j=0; $j -lt $itemki.Count; $j++)
{
    $itemki[$j].ResetRoleInheritance()
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

This works like a charm now.